# How to handle custom coap options (non-standard)

Tags: java, coap, californium

I‘m working on a openHAB2 binding for the Shelly series of devices. The http interface is running well, but I can‘t register to get the COAP events.

Does someone has experience with the Californium framework? Shelly uses non-standard Coap options (based on their CoIoT specification: https://shelly-api-docs.shelly.cloud/images/CoIoT%20for%20Shelly%20devices%20(rev%201.0)%20.pdf).

I'm using the Java Californium framework.

When I register the observer no callback is performed. If I send a command I see ACKs in the log, but they report an unknown option 3332, which Shelly describes in their doc. I didn‘t found a way to register/inject custom options to the Californium framework so the observer can read them. Any help is appreciated.

```java
    CoapClient           client;
    CoapObserveRelation  relation;

    public void start() {
        client = new CoapClient("coap://192.168.1.1:5683/cit/d");
        client.get(new CoapHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onLoad(CoapResponse response) {
                String content = response.getResponseText();
                logger.debug("RESPONSE 3: " + content);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                logger.warn("FAILED");
            }
        });

        relation = client.observe(
                new CoapHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoad(CoapResponse response) {
                        String content = response.getResponseText();
                        logger.debug("NOTIFICATION: " + content);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        logger.warn("OBSERVING FAILED (press enter to exit)");
                    }
                });
```

What I see in the debug log:

```
Aug 19, 2019 4:15:39 PM org.eclipse.californium.core.network.Matcher receiveResponse
INFORMATION: Ignoring unmatchable piggy-backed response from /192.168.6.81:5683: ACK-2.05   MID= 5718, Token=, OptionSet={"Unknown (3332)":0x534853572d3231233535394635352331}, "{"blk":[{"I":0,"D":"Rela".. 420 bytes
```

- obviously the device is responding (ip:port, uri)
- the packet gets decoded
- data looks ok in general (as described in the spec)
- but it shows "OptionSet={"Unknown (3332)"..."

I have no clue how to register custom options with Californium. It seems that those packets get ignored so the application doesn't get any data.

Any idea?

Comment: I can't help you with the options part, but given the "unmatchable piggy-backed" line indicates a common error with the server, I think it would help understand your overall situation if you could capture the exchanged CoAP packages with wireshark and provide a dump file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you provide logs for both client and server, for requests and responses.
However, I see the ACK response does not include a token (which should be the same as in request), apparently this is why Californium can't match it to a corresponding request.

Californium should work well with custom options.

Try reaching them after you fix the response mathching issue.
That's how it is suppossed to be:

```
response.getOptions().getOthers()
```

That "Unknown ..." message is just because Californium message formatter does not know how to log it properly. You should be able to get it from options anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `MessageInterceptor` to the `CoapEndpoint`. That will call `interceptor.receiveResponse(response);` before the `Matcher` ignores that `Response`. You may throw an exception there to stop the standard processing.
If you want to implement you own Request/Response matching, you may also record the outgoing Requests in `interceptor.sendRequest(Request request);`

But with the rest of the processing, your on your own.